# Read out CSV data within the projectfile in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a webpage for a Raspberry Pi to show data. There are a lot of sensors connected to it and all the data is stored in CSV files. Currently, the files can be read out using a local HTTP connection to my app in java. My question is, is it possible to put an HTML page inside this project file so I can have a nice display on the pi for customers. I want to read this data without the use of an input tag, just show what is already inside the project. I can't touch the files themselves (or at least don't want to).

The ultimate goal is to have a futuristic display for the stored data on the PI. Without the use of a global webserver.

Example of the projectile

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: "Without the use of a webserver", but you're already serving the files over HTTP.

Comment: Yea, but i do that using a local connection. I don't know how difficult it is to use it as a webserver :(